# How to implement startActivityForResult - react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to `startActivityForResult` with a custom Intent's, but I think react native doesn't supported it.

what is the best solution to implement it?

my `startActivityForResult` function:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); // set payment parameters
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(pakageName, "wish.*.*"));
        intent.putExtra("paymentId", paymentId);
        this.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,RETURN_PAYMENT);
```

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but this is how I solved it.

Hope this will help others.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75144449/3080858

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question is 2 years old but I could give you a suggestion if anyone still need a solution.

In React we do have `React hooks, React context` that allowed you to share data between react components.

`Besides that you able to use redux/mobx to handle data flow but I do not recommend it because of using the complex things to solve a small issue.`

In cases of using react-navigation, you able to combine react hooks with react-navigation hooks to receive callback data.

Comment: I cannot understand your answer. How can I get the result on Js funcation?

Answer (score -2):

You can write a custom module for starting the activity and you can use callbacks to send activity result to the react side.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android