# How to use Activity Results API in react native android?

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to create android `native module` for `react native` and I am using [Activity Results API](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) to start another activity. But `registerForActivityResult` is not found, even I have these two dependencies listed in the Gradle:

```
implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.2.0"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0"
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(new GetContent(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
            // Handle the returned Uri
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late to the party. But I had the same issue, and I thought I should share how I solved this hoping it would help others.

First I created a new interface (in it's own file) to have a contract between the MainActivity and the React Native module:

```
public interface OnActivityResultImplementation<S, T> {
    S execute(T a);
}
```

In my MainActivity I have this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
protected OnActivityResultImplementation onActivityResultImplementation = null;
protected ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mStartForResult = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
            onActivityResultImplementation.execute(result);
        });
   ...
}
```

And then in the React Native Module I set it up the like this:

```
public class RCTPushProvisioningModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

@ReactMethod
public void callNativeApiMethod(final Promise promise) {
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) this.getReactApplicationContext().getCurrentActivity();
    activity.onActivityResultImplementation = result -> {
        ActivityResult activityResult = (ActivityResult) result;
        switch (activityResult.getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                promise.resolve(OK);
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                promise.resolve(CANCELED);
                break;
            default:
                promise.reject(ERROR_CODE, "FAILED");
                break;
        }
        return null;
    };

    // Use the ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> from MainActivity to wire the whole thing up.
    fictiveNativeApi.callMethodThatRequiresActivityResultLauncher(activity.mStartForResult);
  }
}
```

Comment: How to do this for the new architecture using TurboModules. Can you help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75576907/how-to-use-registerforactivityresult-with-turbomodules-in-react-natives-new-arc