# Error in resolving registerForActivityResult while using in react-native NativeModule

Tags: android, react-native, registerforactivityresult

I am creating a react-native app in which I need to take permissions from user to access `coarse-location` and `fine-location`.
I have made a Native Module in android and am using the new Activity Result API
[ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions)  for this.

I have added the following in my build.grade

```
implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3"
```

I have declared the ActivityResultLauncher as a member variable on my NativeModule class.

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> requestPermissionLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(), permissions -> {
        Log.d(TAG, "result launcher permissions : " + permissions);
    });
```

```
private boolean checkLocationPermission() {
int isFineLocationPermissionGanted = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getReactApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
int isCoarseLocationPermissionGanted = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getReactApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
return isFineLocationPermissionGanted == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && isCoarseLocationPermissionGanted == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

private void askLocationPermission() {
if(checkLocationPermission()) {
    // location permission is already there
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
        if (Objects.requireNonNull(activity).shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ||
                Objects.requireNonNull(activity).shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
            showMessageOKCancel("Please grant location access which is required to search for devices via bluetooth.", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: inside onclick yes");
                    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION});
                }
            });
        } else {
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION});
        }
    }
}
```

And I am checking and requesting permission in the above functions. I intend to call `askLocationPermission()` function in my `ReactMethod` from my react-native code in useEffect hook in my react-native screen.

The issue that I am facing is that android is not able to find registerForActivityResult() function and is giving the following error on running `npx react-native run-android`.

> Cannot resolve method 'registerForActivityResult' in 'BLEDeviceScanModule'

Comment: `registerForActivityResult` is a method on your activity (specifically on subclasses of `ComponentActivity` such as `FragmentActivity` or `AppCompatActivity`).

Comment: @ianhanniballake In react-native the MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity.
Is there any way in which I can use `registerForActivityResult ` in NativeModule i.e. not a direct Activity per se?

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but this is how I solved it.

Hope this will help others.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75144449/3080858