# Using start activity for result in React Native module

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-native-module

I have native module in my React application, I want to navigate the user to the settings

```
   @ReactMethod
    public void manageStoragePermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
            if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
                Intent getpermission = new Intent();
                getpermission.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                reactContext.getCurrentActivity().startActivity(getpermission);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to wait for the result when the user returns after `granting/not granting` permissions. So I tried to start the activity with `startActivityForResult()`, but I don't have `onActivtyResult()` callback in my module.
I also saw that `startActivityForResult()` is deprecated and I should use `registerForActivityResult` instead, but I also don't have this method in React's native module.
What is the correct way to wait for the activity result when dealing with native modules?

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but this is how I solved it.

Hope this will help others.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75144449/3080858

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use AsyncTask to handle the request.

```
public abstract class AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {
    @WorkerThread
    protected abstract Result doInBackground(Params... params);
    @MainThread
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }
    @SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration"})
    @MainThread
    protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think AsyncTask is deprecated when using api 30 and above.

Comment: Yes it is, However. I think you may consider the alternative approach.Let me share you the link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767733/the-asynctask-api-is-deprecated-in-android-11-what-are-the-alternatives